# Will HSQL to H2 Migration solve the issue of unused space in HSQL DB?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, h2

We have hibernate-hsql combination in file mode. In production, we found that .lob file is growing and now it's size is about 2.5GB. We manually checked data content and it is only 2 MB.

After going through several hsql forums, we noticed that space will not be reclaimed from .lob file even after deleting clob records. That’s why .lob file size is keep on increasing and eventually backup takes too long.

This is the reason of going for migration to H2. Will this solve the problem?

Comment: it is being set as false.   <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an application that uses lobs and deletes some of them, the space will be reused for future lobs.

In normal application use, the `DELETE` statement is used to delete rows. This statement de-allocate the lob space for reuse.

You can design your tests in a way that recreates the database, rather than reuse the old database after removing the data. But this will be so so so costly. So there is no way in HSQL.

I don't know much about H2, When I say `Delete` and if there is some mechanism in H2 to not only de-allocate space but also physical delete (IO) on file then migration will help you.

Please refer this link [HSQLDB and .lobs file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921277/hsqldb-and-lobs-file-size) in answer its described nicely and if you go though last comment on answer you will find your answer.

Comment: H2 uses maximum ~1 GB for inserting 1000 x 8 MB files in the db-file. H2 when adding and right after deleting uses ~68 MB in the db-file. H2 when dropping the database/table reduces the db-file size. This makes me thinking if H2 is a better choice if I'd like to reduce disk space usage.

Comment: The comments on the old answer do not apply to newer versions of HSQLDB, which can compress the lobs and truncate the file at CHECKPOINT.

Comment: Compression setting helped me to reduce the .lob file size. But even with latest version 2.3.2; on command 'CHECKPOINT DEFRAG' execution, it reclaimed space from end of the file only.

Comment: The rest of the space is inside the file and will be reused when new lobs are inserted.

Comment: Rest of the space will be utilized later. That's fine. But for us the large size of .lob file is the problem for backup process, even though space will get utilized later. So I am thinking to change the backup process. Open a new database (the backup database) and copy via SQL the data from the main database to the backup database.

Comment: @Dinil, This process will take too long time.

Comment: @Amogh, Since our db contains less data, comparatively it will take less time than backinup 2.5GB data.

Comment: How can I copy content from one hsql db to another hsql db, which are in file mode. I couldn't find any sql script to do this. Any way?

Comment: @Dinil WE are going a bit off topic now but, to dump hsqldb file using either the embedded or file/server mode sql tools dialog use: `SCRIPT 'c:\path\without\spaces\to\DB\db_sql.sql';` or you can read @ http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html#sqltool_csv-sect

Answer (score 1):

The space for the HSQLDB's .lob file file is reclaimed after each CHECKPOINT. The reclaimed space is then used for new lobs.

It is not normal for a production server to insert large amounts of lobs only once, without adding more after deleting the older data. So this schema works for most use-cases.

You can clear the .lobs file when very little data is stored.

1. Use ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c SET DATA TYPE to change the type of all the CLOB and BLOB columns to VARCHAR(100000000).
2. SHUTDOWN the database and delete the .lobs file.
3. Open the database and use ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c SET DATA TYPE to change the type back to CLOB or BLOB.

HSQLDB is different from most other open-source databases as it has a dedicated file for lobs. Management of lobs is separate from normal data because large lob data does not impact access to smaller data for non-lob columns. You can also use compression for lobs together with a smaller LOB SCALE to reduce their storage space without impacting normal data.

Comment: CHECKPOINT reclaims only the unused space from end of lob file ,unused spaces in front and middle portion of the .lob file will be remaining unclaimed.

Comment: The rest of the free space is inside the file and will be reused when new lobs are inserted.